# ConcurrentDictionary used yet resulting in Thread error

Tags: wpf, vb.net, multithreading

I am using one backgroundworker which runs the Tasks.Parallel.  Following the Code:

```
Public Class SlidertoCanvasBlackWhite
    Implements IValueConverter
    Dim li As New Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary(Of Integer, ImageBrush)

    Public Sub New()
        Dim bw As New ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker
        AddHandler bw.DoWork, AddressOf bwworkmain
        bw.RunWorkerAsync()

        'For i = 0 To 1535
        '    ' bw.RunWorkerAsync(i)
        'Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub bwworkmain(sender As Object, e As ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs)
        Dim c As New SlidertoSolidColorBrush
        Tasks.Parallel.For(0, 1535, Sub(i)
                                        GetImageBrush(i, CType(c.Convert(i, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing), SolidColorBrush).Color())
                                    End Sub)
    End Sub

    Private Sub GetImageBrush(ByVal i As Integer, ByVal c As Color)
        li.TryAdd(i, BlackWhiteColorGenerator(c))
    End Sub


    Public Function Convert(value As Object, targetType As System.Type, parameter As Object, culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter.Convert
        If li.ContainsKey(value) Then
            Try
                Return li(value)
            Catch ex As Exception
                Return Nothing
            End Try
        Else
            Try
                Dim c As New SlidertoSolidColorBrush
                Dim z As ImageBrush = BlackWhiteColorGenerator(
                    CType(c.Convert(value, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing), SolidColorBrush).Color)
                Try
                    li.TryAdd(value, z)
                    Return z
                Catch ex As Exception
                    Return li(value)
                End Try
            Catch ex As Exception
                Return Nothing
            End Try
        End If
    End Function

    Public Function ConvertBack(value As Object, targetType As System.Type, parameter As Object, culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter.ConvertBack
        Throw New NotImplementedException
    End Function

    Private Function BlackWhiteColorGenerator(ByVal Value As Color) As ImageBrush
       '
       'Code for Returns ImageBrush
    End Function

End Class
```

Error I get is : `Cannot use a DependencyObject that belongs to a different thread than its parent Freezable.`

I am using thread safe dictionary i.e. ConcurrentDictionary, coudl you please tell me where the mistake is.  and also this class is a converter Binded in WPF Window.

Comment: Can you indicate the line where the error is thrown? It's probably in Convert or BlackWhiteColorGenerator.

Comment: The error is occuring in convert when accessing value that is added to the concurrentdictionary from another thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is quite clear:

You are using a DependencyObject that 'belongs' to the GUI thread from your Bgw/Parallel code.

The Dictionary is not the only issue when parallelizing this.

Also: It's always a good practice to add a CompletedHandler to a bgw for error handling.

Comment: The ConcurrentDictionary is on the main thread and values are added through multple threads, why cant I access these values, and how can I come around it.  Thank you for your support.

Comment: The Dictionary is not the problem. The error is raised by  some Control or Image object.

Comment: A Canvas.background Property is uses this class as a converter class.

Comment: OK, I missed the base class. There is only limited room for making a Convertor or Validator work concurrently. `value` is the life grenade here.

Comment: So multi threading does not work in here?, I mean no possible alternative is easy here, between the UI and value access in converter

Comment: Probably not. Not 100% sure without full code and stack-trace.

Comment: I am not able to get a stack trace information because not even the Try catch block is catching the error.  For now I will try for an alternative way to get the same thing done.

Comment: Thank you for the time and knowledge shared.